# c# list select unexpected (for me) behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
1. var test = new List<foo>() { new foo { prop1 ="1prop1", prop2 = "1prop2" }, new foo { prop1 = "2prop1", prop2 = "2prop2" }  };

2. var test2 = test.Select(x => x.prop1 = "changed");

3. var test3 = test2.First();
```

Please, explain this behaviour to me. 
Why foo.prop1 values change after line 3?

Comment: What exactly were you expecting it to do that it didn't?

Comment: You need to change x.prop1 = "changed" to x.prop1 == "changed". The == is the equality test

Comment: I sincerely apologize, but why the heck did you all decide that I need to change '=' to '=='? Like really, why? Is question "Why values change?' is not clear enough or something?

Comment: @d.maciej 3 Good answers and 1 comment explain you why the value changes (btw. it changes after line 2, not 3). Not only that, you were offered a solution that would solve your problem. Why do you think we didn't understand your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to do with deferred execution. Most linq methods defer execution until the resulting enumerable is actually enumerated. So when you run the Select statement it just creates an Enumerable that is ready to run the appropriate selector.

When you call `First` on the enumerable it runs the transform on the first item, thus changing its value.

This all assumes that you intended to write `x.prop1 = "changed"` and not `x.prop1 == "changed"`. The former is the assignment operator which sets the value of `x.prop1` and returns the set value. The latter is the equality operator and will return a boolean based on whether they are equal or not.

Comment: Yes. Defered execution.
If the second line of code were test2 = test.select(x => {x.prop1 = changed; return x});
and 3rd line were calling enumerator, everything would be OK.

But you see, in given example test2 is going to be List<string>, to be precise {'changed', 'changed'}. Why calling enumerator on it changes values of 'test' which is List<foo>?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Changing the second line to what you have quoted will do the exact same thing as the second line you have. Also in the given example test2 is *not* going to be of type `List<string>` but `IEnumerable<string>`. Why does calling enumerator change values of test? Because that's what you told it to do. You used an assignment to change the value of prop1 and when it iterated the first item it ran the code you told it to and changed the value.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is assignment, which means it actually changes values.

You want to use `==` instead, to **check** for equality.

Try:

`var test2 = test.Select(x => x.prop1`**==**`"changed");`

Answer (score 1):

You are making an assignment `=` when you probably want to make an equality comparison `==`.

```
 var test2 = test.Select(x => x.prop1 == "changed");
```